# Proper Large Enum Design

Tags: c#, architecture, enums

I've recently completed work on a molecular/protein viewer for a computer graphics class.  Atoms are obviously a very important part of such a program.  Currently, I have a big enum that contains each Element (Hydrogen, Helium, etc).  Each Element has associated information such as color, radius, etc.  I'm using an extension class so I can write:

```
float r = Element.Neon.Radius();
```

I also need to be able to get the corresponding enum from it's symbol.  I stuck that method in the extension class which is a bit messy:

```
Element carbon = ElementExtensions.FromAbbreviation("C");
```

I want to associate a lot more data with particular Element entries but I'm not sure if this is a good design or not.  Currently each set of associated data requires a Dictionary to grab the associated data.  Perhaps I could use a Dictionar?

If I went with an Element class I'd need to make sure there's only even one instance of hydrogen, one of helium, etc.  I like how System.Drawing.Color is designed but I don't think that's exactly what I need (you'd never have to look up associated data for ForestGreen for example).

**What's the best way to support a large but well-defined and finite number of specific instances?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum doesn't seem a very adequate approach to this problem; instead you should create an `Element` class with all the information associated to each element, and static readonly properties for each known element:

```
public class Element
{
    private readonly string _symbol;
    private readonly int _atomicNumber;
    private readonly Color _color


    // Private constructor, since you don't want people to be able to "invent" random elements...
    private Element(string symbol, int atomicNumber, Color color)
    {
        _symbol = symbol;
        _atomicNumber = atomicNumber;
        _color = color;
    }

    public string Symbol { get { return _symbol; } }
    public int AtomicNumber { get { return _atomicNumber; } }
    public Color color { get { return _color; } }


    // Known elements

    private static readonly Element _hydrogen = new Element("H", 1, Color.White);
    private static readonly Element _carbon = new Element("C", 6, Color.Black);
    private static readonly Element _oxygen = new Element("O", 8, Color.Red);


    public static Element Hydrogen { get { return _hydrogen; } }
    public static Element Carbon { get { return _carbon; } }
    public static Element Oxygen { get { return _oxygen; } }


    ...

}
```

This way all information about an element can be in one place, rather than scattered in many different places

Comment: I spend half my time in Java and their version of enum is more like this...  I think that's why I was trying to force it into an enum to being with

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of enums you should reconsider if you should be using inheritance instead.

Instead of Element.Neon why not let Neon inherit from Element?

```
class Element
 int Radius();
 Color Color();
 string Symbol();

class Neon : Element
 int Radius (return x);
 int Color (return Color.Red);
 int Symbol (return "NE");
```

If you only need one element, consider using a Singleton.

Comment: Either an abstract class with some default logic or indeed, an interface.

Comment: I think this would be the best way as I recall from my chem classes there are groups of elements in the periodic table that are similar to each other. They should in this case share the same base class

Comment: I spend half my time in Java and their version of enum is more like this...  This is the pattern I wanted to express

Answer (score 1):

Define your elements as classes, but use the [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) pattern.